# Is it possible to extend IServiceProvider during runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

**TLDR:** Is it possible to modify the `IServiceProvider` after the Startup has ran?

I am running dll's (which implement a interface of me) during run-time. Therefore there's a file listener background job, which waits till the plugin-dll is dropped. Now I want to register classes of this dll to the dependency-injection system. Therefore I added `IServiceCollection` as a Singleton to the DI inside `ConfigureServices` to use inside another method.

In therefore I created a test-project and just tried to modify the `ServiceCollection` in the controller, because it was easier than stripping the background job down.

```cs
services.AddSingleton<IServiceCollection>(services);
```

So I added `IServiceCollection` to my controller to check if I can add a class to the DI after the `Startup` class has ran.

```cs
[Route("api/v1/test")]
public class TestController : Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller
{
  private readonly IServiceCollection _services;

  public TestController(IServiceCollection services)
  {
    _services = services;

    var myInterface = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IMyInterface>();
    if (myInterface == null)
    {
      //check if dll exist and load it
      //....
      var implementation = new ForeignClassFromExternalDll();
      _services.AddSingleton<IMyInterface>(implementation);
    }
  }

  [HttpGet]
  public IActionResult Test()
  {
    var myInterface = HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IMyInterface>();
    return Json(myInterface.DoSomething());
  }
}

public interface IMyInterface { /* ... */ }

public class ForeignClassFromExternalDll : IMyInterface { /* ... */ }
```

The Service was successfully added to the `IServiceCollection`, but the change is not persisted yet to `HttpContext.RequestServices` even after multiple calls the service count increases each time but I don't get the reference by the `IServiceProvider`.

Now my question is: Is that possible to achieve and yes how. Or should I rather not do that?

Comment: Short answer: **No**.

Comment: This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Provide a [mcve] that clarifies your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're trying to achieve..

Comment: In the actual code is it a list? I would suggest you show an example more closely related to your actual situation. Include an actual scenario. Most time a list is not registered as a service so your list example will cause confusion.

Comment: As @Nkosi states, the answer is no. In terms of finding an alternative, the obvious question is *why* do you need to add the service inside of a controller?

Comment: @KirkLarkin It's not about the Controller itself (It was just a quick way for me to test to modify the IServiceCollection in a stripped down project, after the Startup has ran). There's a file listener background job, which waits till the plugin-dll is dropped.

Comment: Sure, that makes sense. I suggest rewriting the question with your requirements (X) rather than your failed solution (Y). Ultimately, I think it's going to be a factory of sorts as answered by @Nkosi.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it possible to modify the IServiceProvider after the Startup has ran?

Short answer: **No**.

Once `IServiceCollection.BuildServiceProvider()` has been invoked, any changes to the collection has no effect on the built provider.

Use a factory delegate to defer the loading of the external implementation but this has to be done at start up like the rest of registration.

```
services.AddSingleton<IMyInterface>(_ => {
    //check if dll exist and load it
    //....
    var implementation = new ForeignClassFromExternalDll();
    return implementation;
});
```

You can now explicitly inject your interface into the controller constructor

```
private readonly IMyInterface myInterface;

public MyController(IMyInterface myInterface) {
    this.myInterface = myInterface;
}

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult MyAction() {
    return Json(myInterface.DoSomething());
}
```

and the load dll logic will be invoked when that interface is being resolved  as the controller is resolved.

Comment: Just curious. Can't you build it again using services.BuildServiceProvider()? What would be the effect?

Comment: [BuildServiceProvider](https://github.com/aspnet/DependencyInjection/blob/master/src/DI/ServiceCollectionContainerBuilderExtensions.cs) is an extension method which returns a completely new service provider which then would need to be replacing all the references to the old ServiceProvider within the whole application. (including references in aspnetcore, 3rdparty libs, your code and so on) wich seems unreasonable when you can solve it with a factroy.